# Show checkbox checked when dialog reopens

Tags: android

I have a dialog box in which I have a listView of checkbox and textview. I have displayed stName Arraylist in textView. Now what I want is after selecting the checkboxes when I reopen the dialog it should show checboxes checked.

```
public class StudentNameAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    Context context;
    BaseActivity activity;
    ArrayList<String> updatedList,studentId,studentIdUpdated;
    ArrayList<CheckModelClass> stName;

    public StudentNameAdapter(Context context, BaseActivity activity, ArrayList<CheckModelClass> stName, ArrayList<String> updatedList, ArrayList<String> studentId, ArrayList<String> studentIdUpdated) {

        super(context, R.layout.student_name_listview,stName);
        this.context = context;
        this.stName = stName;
        this.activity =activity;
        this.updatedList =updatedList;
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentIdUpdated = studentIdUpdated;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        CheckBox checkbox;
        TextView text;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_name_listview, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    stName.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                    if(isChecked){

                        if(studentIdUpdated.contains(studentId.get(getPosition))){

                        }
                        else{

                            updatedList.add(stName.get(getPosition).getName());
                            studentIdUpdated.add(studentId.get(getPosition));
                        }

                    }else

                        {

                        updatedList.remove(stName.get(getPosition).getName());
                        studentIdUpdated.remove(studentId.get(getPosition));
                    }



                }

            });

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.text1, viewHolder.text);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.checkbox, viewHolder.checkbox);
        }
        else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position);

        viewHolder.text.setText(stName.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(stName.get(position).isSelected());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(stName.get(position).isSelected());

    viewHolder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;

             if (cb.isChecked()) {

                    if(studentIdUpdated.contains(studentId.get(getPosition))){

                    }
                    else{

                        updatedList.add(stName.get(getPosition).getName());
                        studentIdUpdated.add(studentId.get(getPosition));
                    }

                }else

                    {

                    updatedList.remove(stName.get(getPosition).getName());
                    studentIdUpdated.remove(studentId.get(getPosition));
                }

        }
    });
```

Comment: this will not work. your answer has nothing related to my question. what i want is once i select any checkbox and close dialog. then when i reopen the dailog it should be seen checked.

Comment: you have used checkedChangeListner which will not work perfectly with viewholder. Because viewholder has capability to store upto 10 rows at a time so when you scroll then checkdChangeListner will change the value to false. Thats why you can use onClickListner ,because onClickListner will work only if you will click on it